# How to replace NAN values from csv files using pandas and then store it into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to store csv files data into mysql using python pandas.

My csv files have a "NAN" & "-INF" values so I want to change it value to 0 and -999 respectively.

But, for now I'm stuck trying to convert the "NAN" to 0.

Already did some google-ing but still cannot figure out how to do it.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import mysql.connector
    import sqlalchemy

    df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
    df1 = df.replace(to_replace="NAN", value="-", inplace=True)

    database_username = 'root'
    database_password = 'password'
    database_ip       = '127.0.0.1'
    database_name     = 'sampledb'
    database_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}: 
                                         {1}@{2}/{3}'.format(database_username, 
                                         database_password, database_ip, 
                                         database_name), pool_recycle=1, 
                                         pool_timeout=57600).connect()

   df.to_sql(con=database_connection, name='test', 
             if_exists='append',chunksize=100)

   df1.to_sql(con=database_connection, name='test', 
              if_exists='append',chunksize=100)
   database_connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently the "NAN" and "-INF" in my data was something like this "           NAN". Same goes for "-INF". There is space in front of the "NAN" and "-INF". After changing the coding to follow the data. I able to change "NAN" and "-INF" value to 0.